# Two similar sums round up the result differently

Tags: javascript, bigdecimal, processor

So the question is pretty straight forward. I cant understand why sums in the example below round up result differently.
I tried using decimal.js but given output is the same.
The main problem is that I'm using result.toFixed(2), which in this case gives to different numbers

[image]